# Why should Java's value-based classes not be serialized?

Tags: java, serialization, java-8

Since Version 8 Java has the concept of [*value-based* classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html). This is in preparation of a future version which will most likely allow the definition of [value types](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html). Both definitions/descriptions mention serialization (bold face added by me):

About the existing value-based classes:

> A program may produce unpredictable results if it attempts to distinguish two references to equal values of a value-based class, whether directly via reference equality or indirectly via an appeal to synchronization, identity hashing, **serialization**, or any other identity-sensitive mechanism.

About future value types:

> The default identity-based hash code for object, available via System.identityHashCode, also does not apply to value types. Internal operations like **serialization** which make identity-based distinctions of objects would either not apply to values (as they do not apply to primitives) or else they would use the value-based distinction supplied by the value type’s hashCode method.

Because future JVM implementations might not use object headers and reference pointers for value-based classes, some of the limitations are clear. (E.g. not locking on an identity which the JVM must not uphold. A reference on which is locked could be removed and replaced by another later, which makes releasing the lock pointless and will cause deadlocks).

But I don't get how serialization plays into this. Why is it considered an *"identity-sensitive mechanism"*? Why does it *"make identity-based distinctions of objects"*?

Comment: The actual question and the question in the topic are completely distinct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Serialization uses `System.identityHashCode` (via `IdentityHashMap`) to ensure that the topology of the object graph resulting from deserialization is topologically equivalent to that of the input graph.

Comment: This is my point -- identity is primarily relevant to graph algorithms to preserve topology; ie, avoid looping on cycles.

Comment: This answer only points out why identity may play a role in the deserialization process. However, I cannot see why that means that “value-based classes [should] not be serialized,” which seems to be the original question. (Even if the OP seems to be satisfied with the answer.)

Comment: What would be the alternative to this ? How would I serialize an object that   has a localdate field

Comment: Also, if this was the case why make LocalDate Serializable?

Comment: Why does LocalDateTime implements Serializable?

Comment: @MichaelPiefel this answer only addresses the question at the end of the OP’s post, “Why is it considered an ‘identity-sensitive mechanism’?” Unfortunately, this ignores the OP’s misconception. The cited documentation does nowhere say that Serialization was forbidden for value based classes (as noted by others, specific examples declare `Serializable`). The documentation rather says programs must not use Serialization “to distinguish two references to equal values of a value-based class”. If you do not rely on Serialization’s topology preserving for value based classes, you’re fine.

Answer (score 6):

Think what happens when the object graph being serialized has a cycle. The serialization algorithm would enter an endless loop in such a case—unless it has a specific mechanism to detect and resolve cycles. We all know that Java's serialization allows cyclic object graphs, therefore the mechanism is there.

Now consider the *definition* of a cycle: the graph contains an object which is reachable from itself. That definition refers to object's *identity*, which means that the mechanism must consider object identity to track cycles. On the implementation level this is achieved by maintaining an `IdentityHashMap` of all seen instances, and that class relies on `Object.identityHashCode()`.

The sentence you quote explains how this issue will be resolved in a future version of Java: value types will be given special treatment such that the cycle detection will rely on their own `equals` and `hashCode` methods instead of `==` and `identityHashCode`.