# Field getting serialized without implementing Serializable interface

Tags: java, serialization, jackson-databind

I have a java class that implements Serializable interface. It has String, BigDecimal and other java predefined types which are serializable. It also includes a custom defined class that doesn’t implement Serializable. The custom type is also getting serialized into JSON.

But there are warnings showing either make it transient or make the custom type implement serializable.

How is the type getting serialized even though it doesn’t implement Serializable ? And Should I ignore the warnings ( SonarLint messages) ?

Comment: By JSON. Evidently it either has a bug or doesn't care.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Jackson doesn't use `java.lang.Serializable` type hints when serializing/deserializing. Jackson can serialize/deserialise most of the Java types. Have a look at `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std` and `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std`. If you use `ObjectMapper`, you could configure required feature as in this [guide](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features).

Ignoring warnings depends on your object types. For example, there's a good discussion about value type serialization.

[Why should Java's value-based classes not be serialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451590/why-should-javas-value-based-classes-not-be-serialized)

Comment: So where does implementing Serializable be useful ? Also to remove warnings I added transient keyword to the type, that should be fine right as Jackson ignores it

Comment: *"So where does implementing Serializable be useful ? "* - For example, when using the Java standard object serialization mechanism! ObjectInputStream / ObjectOutputStream.  Jackson is a 3rd-party library.

Comment: @StephenC So JPA uses this mechanism ?

Comment: I didn't say that.   But http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/do_jpa_entities_have_to